# Write a function in Python to group by and generate a boxplot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, custom-function

Python novice here, In the dataframe below, I need assistance writing a function that does the following:

I: select columns `year`,`state`,`dept`, `revenue(mil)`

II: boxplot of `revenue(mil) ~ dept` for each unique `state` of a unique `year`, something along the lines of `groupby(['year','state])`

III: export the graph as a `2-figure per page` pdf file

```
# the dataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df1={
'xcode':[5001,5001,5250,5250,5425,5425,5610,5610,5910,5910,5010,5010,6110,6110,6135,6135,6220,6220,6550,6550],
'town':["A01","A01","A01","A02","A01","A02","A03","A03","A01","A02","A03","A04","A01","A01","A01","A01","A01","A01","A02","A02"],
'state':["PA","PA","NY","NY","DE","DE","PA","PA","NY","NY","PA","PA","NY","NY","DE","DE","PA","PA","NY","NY"],
'dept':["hlth",'edu','edu','hlth','hlth','edu','hlth','edu','edu','hlth','edu','hlth','hlth','edu','hlth',"hlth",'edu','edu','hlth','hlth'],
'year':[2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004],
'revenue(mil)':[112.9,123,124,523.5,112,334,55,449,221.6,332,235,239,235,223,235.6,204,315.5,614,512,514.2],
'tax':[112.0,123,124,523,112,334.5,55,449,221,332,235.6,239,235,223.7,235,204,315,614,512,514.6]
     
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1
```

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf

def boxplot2pdf(df):
    # select the columns
    df = df[['year','state','dept', 'revenue(mil)']]
    # set pdf page
    pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("boxplot2pdf.pdf")
    # set number of graphs per page
    N_plots_per_page = 2
########## Here is where I need help- grouping by year, grouping each year by state and plotting revenue(mil) by dept ###################################################
    #  for each unique year and unique state,boxplot revenue per dept
    for group in groupby(["year","state"]):
        
        g = sns.boxplot(x = dept,y = revenue(mil),data = df[group])
        # the title showing specific year and state
        plt.title("Year:  State: ")
        pdf.savefig(g,fig)
    pdf.close()

#driver code
boxplot2pdf(df1)
```

Kindly share your full code with comments explaining your approach :)

@Abuzar, your output looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def boxplot2pdf(df, nFigPerPage):
    years = df['year'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()
    states = df['state'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()
    
    pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("boxplot2pdf.pdf")
    
    nFig = 0
    iFigPerPage = 0
    for year in years:
        for state in states: 
            df_year_state = df.loc[(df['state'] == state) & (df['year'] == year),['dept','revenue(mil)']]
            title = "Year: {}, State: {}".format(year, state)
            
            if nFig % nFigPerPage == 0:
                fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=nFigPerPage, squeeze=True )

            sns.boxplot(ax=axs[iFigPerPage],  x="dept", y="revenue(mil)", hue='dept', data=df_year_state).set_title(title)
            sns.swarmplot(ax=axs[iFigPerPage], x="dept", y="revenue(mil)", hue='dept', data=df_year_state)
            
            iFigPerPage += 1
            if iFigPerPage % nFigPerPage == 0:
                iFigPerPage = 0

            nFig += 1
            
            if nFig % nFigPerPage == 0:
                fig.tight_layout()
                pdf.savefig()
                plt.close()
                
    pdf.close()
    
df={
'xcode':[5001,5001,5250,5250,5425,5425,5610,5610,5910,5910,5010,5010,6110,6110,6135,6135,6220,6220,6550,6550],
'town':["A01","A01","A01","A02","A01","A02","A03","A03","A01","A02","A03","A04","A01","A01","A01","A01","A01","A01","A02","A02"],
'state':["PA","PA","NY","NY","DE","DE","PA","PA","NY","NY","PA","PA","NY","NY","DE","DE","PA","PA","NY","NY"],
'dept':["hlth",'edu','edu','hlth','hlth','edu','hlth','edu','edu','hlth','edu','hlth','hlth','edu','hlth',"hlth",'edu','edu','hlth','hlth'],
'year':[2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004],
'revenue(mil)':[112.9,123,124,523.5,112,334,55,449,221.6,332,235,239,235,223,235.6,204,315.5,614,512,514.2],
'tax':[112.0,123,124,523,112,334.5,55,449,221,332,235.6,239,235,223.7,235,204,315,614,512,514.6]
     
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
boxplot2pdf(df1, nFigPerPage=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, your code works, however,  some of the boxplots are not visible ( see the attached figure above). can you make them more visible with the whiskers? Also, can we have two graphs per page instead of the one graph per page? Thanks

Comment: @RickyTricky the reason that some of the boxplots are not visible is due to the lack of enough data. I added some swarm plots to visualize this fact. If you want to see more reasonable boxplots please add more data to your dataset.

Comment: @ Abuzar G, Thanks, works like magic!